# Potting sampling result frequency in histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am just starting to learn Matlab.

Case:
From 3 elements, let's say 1,2, and 3. I want to sample 2 elements randomly. I want to simulate it 100 times to see the probability of the outcomes pair. 
How can I plot the result on histogram that I can visualize the frequency of each pair. So far, I can do the sampling :

```
for i=1:100
datasample(1:3,2,'Replace',true)
end
```

So possible outcome is (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,3), etc.
How can I plot the frequency of the outcome using histogram?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 100;

% generate data random
arr = zeros(n, 2);
for i = 1:n
    arr(i, :) = randi([1,3],1,2);
end

% frequency
[ii, jj, kk] = unique(arr, 'rows', 'stable');
f = histc(kk, 1:numel(jj));
result = [ii f];

% plot
cuts = strcat(num2str(result(:,1)), '-',num2str(result(:,2)));
bar(result(:,3))
grid on
xlabel('combination')
ylabel('frequency')
set(gca,'xticklabel',{cuts});
set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',45);
```